# Unable to export HTML Table content to excel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, excel

I am trying to export contents of div to excel sheet by using following code.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" CssClass="btnSearch" 
           OnClick="btnExportToExcel_Click" Text="Export to Excel"/>

protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", ViewState["title"].ToString());
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    divRepwithHeader.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();   
}
```

Everything was working fine until I came upon `webforms` which contains dynamically generated `HTML Table data`. It exports all the contains of div (`Gridviews`,`Literals`), but the data on table isn't exported to excel.

I've searched for other alternatives such as using jquery, javascripts and other codes but the codes didn't work, since many of these answer to being able to export `HTML Table` content only. I want to export all `divRepwithHeaderThere` contents. These are the examples of url I've tried.

- [Export HTML to Excel in ASP.NET](http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/export-html-excel-asp-net/)
- [ASP.NET export dynamic data from div to excel in asp.net](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/export-dynamic-data-from-div-to-excel-in-asp.net-using-jquery-and-c/67968)
- [Export HTML Table to Excel using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364107/export-html-table-to-excel-using-asp-net)
- [Export HTML table to MS Excel Format Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997824/export-html-table-to-ms-excel-format-using-jquery)

Here is the code for the `div` I want to print.

```
<div id="divRepwithHeader" runat="server">
    <div id="divHeader" runat="server" class="DivHdr" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;
        border: 1px;">
        <asp:Label ID="litCompanyName" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="litCompanyAdd" runat="server" Font-Italic="True"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="litRepTitle" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table runat="server" id="tableExtras" width="100%" class="printTable" summary="headers">
        <tr runat="server">
            <th style="width: 50%">Bank Account</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Entry Date</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Fiscal Year</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Month</th>
        </tr>
    </table><br />
    <table runat="server" id="tableReportBank" class="printTableBRS" width="100%" /><br />
    <table runat="server" id="tableReportCash" class="printTableBRS" width="100%" /></div>
```

And this is how the content looks like (img. left) and how it is exported to excel (img. right). [image]

Comment: Good news! There is an answer.... bad news: it's not easy. If you want to fully define everything (and be prepared to bash your head against the wall) then look at OpenXML.  There's a version called ClosedXML which is an intermediately layer to OpenXML that makes life a little easier.

Comment: @HugoYates : Actually I tried to use `OfficeOpenXml`, and like you said to define everything is pain in a**. Though the output is proper excel file you have to define everything from column range, background color, to styling. So I chose the laziest part. I don't have to reformat the content. If any soultion doesn't exist then I will surely use it.

Comment: You could create it as a CSV but as soon as you want to do anything 'excelly' ie merged cells any type of styling you're into OpenXML. I believe you can reference parts of Excel and hook into those but then that'll require that your server is also running Excel. Everything easy option out there is tied to some form of paid license :/ `ClosedXML` (when I last looked at it) looked a promising solution but appeared to have been abandoned.